# How can I overlay text on image in ReactJS/NextJS application?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am having some trouble getting the css styles to apply as intended. I'm writing this application in ReactJS/NextJS. I am trying to create a component that shows an image with text positioned on top of image. I expect the CSS styles that I'm applying to work, because I've already tested the styles through w3schools. I'm attaching screenshot of what I've done in w3schools, what I'm currently doing in my code, and how everything looks in my localhost:3000. The div with ***imageContainer1***, has a background-image applied to it in the css file, but the image is not appearing on screen. The image that does appear is from the second div with inline styling (which I copied from somewhere, can't remember). The thing is that when I remove the inline styles and move the styles inside the style tags or in the css file, the styles no longer want to apply as they did inline. It's quite confusing how the styling is inconsistent when I move it.

Alas, the goal is to show an image, at full width of the viewport, with text positioned on top of the image. I appreciate any pointers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import styles from './HomeContent.module.css'

const Home = () => {

return (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.imageContainer1}></div>
    <p className={styles.text}>
        text
    </p>
 </div>
    
    
  )
}
export default Home


.imageContainer1 {
  background-image: url(../public/redtesla.jpg);
  height: 100%; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: max-content;
  /* position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue; */
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.text{
  position: 'absolute';
  top: '25%';
  left: '10%';
  color: "red";
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding the code as an image, could you please include it as a [code block](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks)? It's hard to reproduce this issue without code.

Comment: @joeymalvinni yes of course. Just added the code.

Comment: Looking at the image result, it looks like the text is in fact over the image. What is wrong?

Comment: The image that is appearing only works with inline code. If I move the inline code else where, it does not work. I tried a different approach. Instead of having an <img> I instead applied a background-image to a div (the first div in the code, see imageContainer1 css class). This is the same as in the w3schools code example. However, the image I'm applying as a background-image doesn't appear.

Comment: @joeymalvinni hi there, I cleaned up the code to minimize confusion. As you can see, the background-image I've applied in the css file is not appearing.

Comment: Oh. In that case, make sure that the image container has a width and height, and has a position tag.

Comment: @joeymalvinni still nothing :/